# Program Closes, cin not working?

Tags: c++, cin

```
char iCharSelect()
{
 //CHARACTER CHOICE
 cout
    << "\n\n\n Choose Your Stoner:\n\n"
    << "\n            1 = Chris\n"
    << "\n            2 = James\n"
    << "\n            3 = Hunter\n"
    << "\n            4 = Antonio (Alt. Route)\n"   
    << "\n\n            Enter Character Number: ";
 int iChar = INITIALIZED;
 cin >> iChar;

 //CHARACTER NAME STRING
 string sCharName;

 //CHARACTER CHECK
     if (iChar == 1){sCharName = "Chris";}
else if (iChar == 2){sCharName = "James";}
else if (iChar == 3){sCharName = "Hunter";}
else if (iChar == 4){sCharName = "Antonio";}
else                { 
                    cout << "\n\n\n\tYOU GET NOTHING!!";
                    system("PAUSE>NUL");
        //PROGRAM CLOSES HERE-------------------------------------
                    cout << iChar;
                    system("PAUSE>NUL");
                    }

char *chCharName = &sCharName[0];

 return *chCharName;     }
```

What am I doing wrong? The program closes at the marked point in the code and trying to print iChar yields nothing..?

Comment: Why the pointer gymnastics at the end of the function? Just `return chCharName[0];` is all that's needed.

Comment: What is your function supposed to return if none of those `if` statements are true?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do:

if (ichar == '1')
 same for 2,3..
The way you do it, is ask if the char inserted hascii is equal to 1/2.. It does not equal, so you get to the last "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer `return *chCharName;` but you've labeled the function as `char`. One of your problems is that you need to label the function to return `char*`

```
char* iCharSelect()
```

Comment: Thats not the problem, I had the exact same piece of code called from a different function and it worked fine. Its only when I put the actual if statement in this function where I ran into issues. There are no compiler errors the window just closes for no reason it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you do not set `chCharName` if none of those conditions in the `if()` statement are true.  If this is the case, you will attempt to return the first character of an empty string, which leads to undefined behavior.

In addition, the end of the function uses pointers when there is no need to use pointers.

A reasonable implementation would look like this:

```
if ( sCharName.empty())
   return '\0';
return sCharName[0];
```